# Get selected date of persianDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, unix, datepicker

With this code, I able to get selected date as unix.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmnaz9sb/)

```
  function getValue() {
      var date = $('#example').data("DateTimePicker").date();
      if( date ){
        alert(date.unix());
      }
    }
```

How about PersianDate, I want to get selected date as unix.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj7amq18/)

Comment: What is the problem? I fixed your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fbo09p25/

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, Could you make it with the button? So during the click I want to access to the data. with your code I should to provide one input for each persianDate, just for having data of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using `getState` method on `persianDatepicker` instance, like this:

```js
var pd = $('#example').persianDatepicker({
  autoClose: true,
  // other options
});

function showUnix() {
  const state = pd.getState();
  alert(state.selected.unixDate);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/lib/persian-date/dist/persian-date.js"></script>
<script src="https://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/lib/persian-datepicker/dist/js/persian-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/persian-datepicker@latest/dist/css/persian-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" id="example" class="initial-value-type-example inline-example leapyear-algorithmic">
<button onclick="showUnix()">show unix</button>
```

Comment: this works fine but how to get this outside of this without the pd varable